# Is it OK not to send ack to OutputCollector?

Tags: apache-storm

Suppose I have a bolt that needs to pass a list of some type.
And if, after calculation, the list is empty, I don't emit.
Does the bolt still need to ack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends:

**If you are not using using RichBolt**, than storm will call `Ack` for you after you exit the the execute method.

**If you are using RichBolt** (what seem to be the case since sometimes you are acking)

If you are using [guarantee messaging](https://storm.incubator.apache.org/documentation/Guaranteeing-message-processing.html) you will need to `ack` the tuple, so the spout `ack` callback will be called.
Also if you are not acking, you will get timeout, so the spout fail callback will be called